# Find a matrix whose right nullspace $\neq$ left nullspace but rowspace $=$ colspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is simple:

> Find a matrix whose right nullspace $\neq$ left nullspace but rowspace $=$ colspace

I thought the inverse symmetric matrix would be a good example for this.

$$
A^T=-A
$$

Let

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & +3\\
-2 & -3 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

See that row space = colspace in this case. the basis's are the inverse of each other but they end up forming the same subspace in $\Bbb R^3$

And you can check the nullspace too, left nullspace isn't equal to the nullspace.

But the answer in the textbook says that it is impossible to find such a vector since for colspace to be equal to row space $m=n$
this would make
$m-r=n-r$

this is what the answer says but this is about equality of degrees of the nullspaces right? such a matrix can be found as i gave in an example :)

help out pls

Answer (score 2):

Let $\DeclareMathOperator{LNull}{LNull}\LNull(A)$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{RNull}{RNull}\RNull(A)$ denote the *left nullspace* and *right nullspace* of $A$ respectively. That is,
\begin{align*}
\LNull(A) &= \{x : x^\top A=\mathbf 0\} &
\RNull(A) &= \{x : Ax=\mathbf 0\} 
\end{align*}

Your $A$ has $\LNull(A)=\RNull(A)$. Indeed, one may check that
$$
\LNull(A)=\RNull(A)=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{\langle3,-2,1\rangle\}
$$

In fact, any matrix satisfying $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row(A)=\DeclareMathOperator{Col}{Col}\Col(A)$ satisfies $\LNull(A)=\RNull(A)$. To check this, recall that for an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ we have
\begin{align*}
\Row(A) &= \{y^\top A:y\in\Bbb R^n\} & \Col(A) &= \{Ay:y\in\Bbb R^n\}
\end{align*}
Then note that
\begin{align*}
x\in\LNull(A)
&\Leftrightarrow x^\top A=\mathbf0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x^\top Ay=0&(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \langle x,Ay\rangle=0&(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n) \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in \Col(A)^\perp \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in\Row(A)^\perp \\
&\Leftrightarrow \langle x,y^\top A\rangle=0 &(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n) \\
&\Leftrightarrow y^\top Ax=0 &(\forall y\in\Bbb R^n)\\
&\Leftrightarrow Ax=\mathbf0\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in \RNull(A)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Your textbook has the right answer, but what you've written is not the full justification.  What should be stated is that the nullspace is the ***orthogonal complement*** of the rowspace, and the left nullspace is the orthogonal complement of the column space.

Of course, *any* square matrix must have right and left null spaces of the same dimension, since the row and column spaces have the same dimension and $m = n$.  What's important for our purposes, however, is that if the row and column spaces are the same space, then the left and right nullspaces must *also* be the same space.

In your particular example, as you stated, the bases you get for the left and right null spaces are bases for the same subspace.  That is, you $A$ has the same left and right null-spaces.  Indeed, this is because $A$ has the same row and column spaces.

In particular, we calculate that both nullspaces of $A$ are the span of $(3,-2,1)$.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding to the example you gave we have that every $x \in \operatorname{null}A$ (A is called a [skew-symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix)) matrix satisfies the equality:
$$A x = 0.$$

But then $x\in \operatorname{null}\left(A^T\right),$ since:
$$A^T x  = - Ax = 0.$$

And also the inverse is true, i.e. if $x \in \operatorname{null}\left(A^T\right),$ then $x\in \operatorname{null}(A).$